# .Net application loses connection to database when multiple users are logged in

Tags: asp.net, database-connection

I have this .net application where each client has their own database and thus their own connection string. The issue that I run into is that when multiple clients are logged in to the application connection to the databases is lost which will give an internal server error (or something similar, depending on the process).
I am not sure what is causing this, whether I should increase the Max Pool size or whether I should try something else.

I have put the `connection.open()` inside a using block, but that did not solve the issue.

I have tried to find a suitable solution, but have had no luck, so I hope the braintrust can help me. Many thanks

Comment: You should use a connect-disconnect stategy rather than have each user with their own connection. i.e. connect to the db only when you need to perform an operation then disconnect.

Comment: @Gregg Thanks for your answer! But aren't I doing that by having the 'connection.open()' inside a '@using' block? As I understood it then the connection is closed when it is done with the db. Or am I really thinking wrong here?

Comment: No you are correct. I was thinking that you were keeping a connection open for each user.  One other thing could be the number of concurrent connections. I would monitor via SQL Profiler in Sql Server Developer Studio and run a trace to see what is happening when the connections start dropping